# Using Yammer embed to display feeds

Tags: yammer

I am using Yammer embed to show a group feed on a page in my ASP.NET MVC3 application. I have created a div whose Id is embedded-feed. I am using below javascript code to show a group feed.

```
<script src="https://assets.yammer.com/assets/platform_embed.js"></script>
<script data-app-id="<<valid app id>>" type="text/javascript">
yam.connect.embedFeed({
    container: "#embedded-feed",
    network: "<<valid-site>>.com",
    feedType: "group",
    feedId: "<<Id for feed>>"
});
```

Upon loading the page, Yammer widget shows up with login button. When I click on login button, it opens up a new browser window and I get a pop up with the message - "The web page you are viewing is trying to close the tab. Do you want to close the tab?" I have already added yammer.com to trusted sites. Please share if you have any thoughts on what am I missing here.
-Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Add yammer.com to trusted sites in Internet Explorer settings...

uncheck the checkbox to very server security.